# <a> tag in <a> tag for seo

Tags: html, seo

Old code:

```
<a href="test.html" class="class1">Image</a>
<a href="test.html" class="class2">Title</a>
<a href="test.html" class="class3">Download</a>
```

New code:

```
<a href="test.html">
   <a href="" class="class1">Image</a>
   <a href="" class="class2">Title</a>
   <a href="" class="class3">Download</a>
</a>
```

I need to keep the classes because otherwise it will screw up the CSS and it's too much to change.
But is the code bad for SEO?

Comment: I don't know about SEO, but I'd avoid nested `A` elements at all times.

Answer (score 5):

It's bad full stop - nested `<a>` elements are [illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) in HTML.

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
<a href="test.html">
    <span class="class1">Image</span>
    <span class="class2">Title</span>
    <span class="class3">Download</span>
</a>
```